# TinyMCE word count in knockout data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, tinymce

I use the TinyMCE Editor and want to assign the word count value to a knockout variable.
Setting up the editor is ok and it shows the word count value, but I cannot understand how I can get the actual value.

This is the View of the knockout value:

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
    No. of words is: <span data-bind="value: TextWordCount"></span>
</div>
```

But how do I connect it to the TinyMce word count?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvKTn/1/

Comment: I'm afraid but with the current implementation of the wordcount plugin: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.js there is no easy way to get the wordcount into an observable without modifying the plugin or duplicating its functionality in your own code...

Comment: I disagree, there is a very simple way to extract the value from the `wordcount` plugin using `editor.plugins['wordcount'].getCount()`.  I shall provide an answer illustrating this shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your fiddle to make it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZvKTn/3/

First of all,

```
<span data-bind="value: TextWordCount"></span>
```

must use the "text" binding instead:

```
<span data-bind="text: TextWordCount"></span>
```

Other than that you need to hook up with TinyMCE onKeyUp event to get live updates while typing text in the editor.

Also your code to clone data was problematic.

I changed the TextWordCount from an observable to a computed:

```
self.TextWordCount = ko.computed(function() {
    // First remove all html tags
    var text = self.TextbatchText().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
    // Tiny MCE inserts an extra &nbsp; at the end if you "double space" the end of your sentence. This replaces it with a normal space
    text = text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    // This merges all spaces and tabs following each other into a single space
    text = text.replace(/[\s\t]+/g, ' ');
    // This removes spaces and the begin and end of the text
    text = text.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');

    // This splits the string into an array of words separated by a space.
    return text.split(' ').length;
});
```

Comment: This is not that easy... it is not enough to just split on  `/[\s\t]+/` so your solution is only working if there is no formatting is used in the editor. See in the http://jsfiddle.net/GssN7/ first select the text: "This is the first text" then click on the align center on the toolbar: No. of word changes from 5 to 7...

Comment: Here is an alternative which handle formatting used by the editor: https://gist.github.com/tamewhale/581361

Comment: nemesv, your fiddle is nearly working, except the TextWordCount does´t update while typing and also it counts double blank as a word. 
Perhaps you could explain the logical expressions as they are greek to me:
What does /[\s\t]+/ do, and what does /(< ([^>]+)<)/g do?

Comment: Hallvar, takk for svar. :) I don´t really understand how I should combine your github code with the fiddle. When sticking the code in the customized binding it still counts double blanks and formatting codes.

Comment: Ingen problem mister! I updated the Fiddle with better word counting code, and it seems to work when I test it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

As promised, all be it a little late, here is my solution.  No need to re-write or hack together anything.  I have even taken the liberty of including this requirement into the latest version of my [tinymce-knockout-binding](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding) of which you can see a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelpapworth/rU3aE/5/).

In short, the key is the following code segment;

```
'setup': function( editor ) {
   editor.on('change keyup nodechange', function( args ) {
       var accessor = allBindings.get( 'wysiwygCount' );
       if (editor.plugins['wordcount']) {
           accessor(editor.plugins['wordcount'].getCount());
       }
   }
}
```